# AWS EFS mount to EC2 Amazon linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Alright everyone, I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I am setting up Apache on a linux EC2 instance on AWS. The install for APACHE was fine following these white papers posted by amazon

[Apache Web Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt2-apache-web-server.html)

Once I get to step 3.C it hits a brick wall. I have also used the EFS mounting documents from Amazon with no luck also.

[Mounting File System](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html)

Once I run:

```
sudo mount -t efs fs-#######:/ /var/www/html/efs-mount-point
```

the command line just hangs up, mount does not complete and eventually times out. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly would be to check the security groups. Is EFS allowing connections from the EC2 instance?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs-create-security-groups.html

Secondly, can you netcat the IP address of the EFS?
e.g nc -vz EFS_IP 2049

Lastly, if you are using custom DNS in your VPC you will not be able to resolve it unless you are using DHCP forwarding in the VPC

Comment: thank you! I'll let you know this afternoon.

Comment: Changed the security group to allow NFS open to everything. Still no luck

Comment: netcat was not a recognized command on this instance.

Comment: No custom DNS, just using the default